# Test whether any files in a given folder are open

Tags: excel, vba

Using the `Name` statement to rename a folder, I get 'Run Time Error 75' if any files are open within the folder or its subfolders.

How can I test whether one or more files are open in a given folder?

Comment: try to follow [this solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291295)

Comment: Thanks Kazz. The solution by Microsoft means I have to test for all files in the folder. The number of file to test is an unwanted overhead. Hence I am looking to see if there is a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to handle the error when it does occur, e.g. by explaining to the user what's going on and repeating the name change attempt until successful.

```
Dim errNo As Lon

Do
    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn off error reporting
    Name oldName As newName
    errNo = Err    ' Save the error number (if any)
    On Error GoTo 0  ' Turn error reporting back on

    'Handle the error
    Select Case errNo
    'Deal with the various cases:
    Case 0
        'No error. All done.
        Exit Do
    Case 75
        'File/path access
        'Explain what's going on and repeat
        MsgBox "Couldn't rename folder. Make sure all files in folder are closed."
    Case Else
        'Some other error occurred.
        'Deal with it here.
    End Select
Loop
```

Could also give the user the option to cancel completely using `MsgBox("Explanatory message",vbOKCancel)`.

Comment: Thank you. I have used the error trapping. Unfortunately it is after the event and I would like to warn before hand. I have in fact used a dummy Name statement first up, trap error and allow to proceed if no error. This solution works, although not elegant. I am wondering if Microsoft allows code to access to folder 'flags' , if any, which will alert if files are open.

Comment: Why do you want to warn the user beforehand? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The macro application I have changes the folder name after user action. If by chance any file is open the application errors out. I trap this and warn the user. What I would like to do is to check if any file is open and request user to close all open file before continuing. Doing it before any user action saves the user the hassle of repeating the data entry. Thanks.

Comment: Well that's exactly what error trapping is for. See my updated example.